# How can I ensure a read only user is created for every new database in SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

We create multiple databases in sql server 2005.  I would like to make sure that every new database that is created has a specific read only account when it gets created.  I know there is a way to write code to do this, but is there a way we can set up a database template of some sort so every time a new database is created the account is automatically added from SQL server side rather than the code side?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean **one** read-only user account for **all** databases on a server, you can use this *hack*:

- Create a new SQL Server login
- Create a new Database user in **model** database with db_datareader privilegues.

All new databases use the **model** db as template, so the user will be available in all databases.

But keep the security issues in mind. ;-)

Comment: Any other ways?  We have a multi-db environment and a service that needs the read only account added to each so security is not an issue.

Joe

Comment: What's missing with this approach?

Comment: Florian, This approach has not had any luck for us so far.  This is the approach we pursued and does not seem to be working as anticipated.  We constantly have to run scripts to add the proper users to the db's afterwards.  

Thanks.